# Office Addin - Ribbon Group control alignment

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-web-addins

I am working on an Office word web addin. In its ribbon menu controls are generated usingthe  manifest file. We create a group and inside the group define controls. As per https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/group?product=access a group can hold a maximum of 6 elements.

I want all controls to be alighed horizontally in the ribbon group. If 3 controls are in a group it's working as expected, but when a group contains four controls then the controls are not arranged as per my expectation. (Please refer to the screenshot).

[image]

I need an alignment like the screenshot below
[image]

Is there any possibility in Office web addin?

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot control it.

Answer (score 1):

Size and alignment of buttons and groups is controlled by Office. What you get will vary depending on the size of the Office window,and the number of buttons in the group. If you make the Word window very large (or full screen), and then resize it slowly to a very small size, you will see the button/group size and alignment change.

Comment: I have resized my browser, eventhough there is no effect in ribbon control alignment.

Comment: My point was that you can't control the alignment. Office decides the best alignment for any given size and you cannot control what window size your users prefer. If you don't get 4 buttons aligned horizontally when the Word window is at it's maximum, then you are never going to get them aligned that way. It may be that Office won't ever align more than 3 horizontally.